# How to add bootstrap CI into this function in R

Tags: statistics-bootstrap

I want to calculate the 90% Confidence interval (Bootstrap) for these two estimations. Harrell-Davis Distribution-Free Quantile Estimator. I think this function is the bootstrapped version of the nonparametric quantile which estimate the mean and standard deviations. Now I was wondering how I can calculate the 90% CI?

```
library(Hmisc)
x <- runif(100)
hdquantile(x, probs =  seq(0.025, 0.975,0.95), se=TRUE,names = TRUE, weights=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hdquantile function computes the estimator and also gives the standard error if you set se=TRUE. To find the confidence interval you can bootstrap it through boot function and get confidence intervals through boot.ci

## Code

```
library(Hmisc)
x <- runif(100)
hdquantile(x, probs =  seq(0.025, 0.975,0.95), se=TRUE,names = TRUE, 
weights=FALSE)
```

## For booting create a statistic

```
library(boot)
hq <- function(x,i) {
hdquantile(x[i], probs =  seq(0.025, 0.975,0.95), se=TRUE,names = TRUE, 
weights=FALSE)
}
bootx <- boot(x,hq,1000)
boot.ci(bootx, conf = 0.90)
```

Comment: thanks so much. I want to calculate the 90% for q=0.025 and q=0.975 at the same time. I was wondering how I can modify your code to have 90%CI for both quantiles. Also I checked the results of the function you kindly made, what is the difference between Normal,Basic ,Studentized,Percentile and BCa . Which one of them should I choose?

Comment: If you wanted to calculate 90% for both. You could modify inside the loop to have two hdquantile results. Then you could run boot.ci for them separately by specifying index in boot.ci. See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/boot/html/boot.ci.html) for more on boot.ci and boostrap intervals